# How to add image in excel sheet using JPhpExcel extension in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I used the  following code to display the data into excel sheet.Now i need  display the logo in excel sheet? How to do this?

```
$info_excel=$_REQUEST['excel_info'];
            $month=$_REQUEST['m']; $year=$_REQUEST['y'];
            $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year); 
            Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel1.JPhpExcel');
            $xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');
            $image="<img src='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/themes/optisol/images/resign-icon.png'."'/>";         
            $heading=array(
             1=>array(" Attendance  for 01"."-".$month."-".$year." To ".$num."-".$month."-".$year." "),
             );
            $value=array(
            1=>array('User Id', 'Emp No','Name','Branch','Designiation','Department','Present Day','Holiday','Leave Day','Week Day','Lop'),
            );


                        $xls->addArray($heading);
                $xls->addArray($value);
                $xls->addArray($info_excel);
                $xls->generateXML('attendance');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try codding as a simple layout in your view component, then try this at the end of the code

```
//code goes here
$this->layout=false;
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel.JPhpExcel');
$xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false);
$xls->generateXML('name_of_the_sheet');
//end of the view
```

This will generate you an excel file to save